# Rails with angular - null value change to 0

Tags: ruby, database, web-applications

When I update some field with null value, 0 appear. DB: Postgres

Angular put request

```
------WebKitFormBoundarygQGLt12slBC759GB
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="product[gender]"
null
```

The field:

```
:gender, 'integer USING CAST(gender AS integer)', {default: nil, null: true}
```

result:
[image: db postgres field]

Comment: Looks like you're type casting your value to an integer, which would mean `nil` is typecast to `0` when inserted.

Comment: Can I change this behavior ?